# How to check for corrupted data files?

Tags: data-recovery, repair

I have millions of files on a filesystem. Most of them are of mainstream file formats (JPEG, DOCX, ZIP, MP3 etc.). Some of them are corrupted, i.e. some blocks of the file have been overwritten by random data. I need a tool which lists, reads and analyzes all files recursively, and gives me a list of the corrupted files. For each file it should: autodetect the file format; if the file contains compressed parts, decompress those parts in memory, and report failures; if the file contains checksums, verify the checksums, and report failures; scan the entire file for structural errors (e.g. the byte following a JPEG segment is not 0xff), and report them. It doesn't have to understand each file format to the tiniest detail, but it should understand a few dozen mainstream file formats, and be able to detect the most blatant corruptions (e.g. the file is truncated; or a 4 KiB block was overwritten with random data, causing a checksum mismatch).

The operating system can be Windows, macOS or Linux, whichever the tool works on.

What I don't need:

- A tool which can only autodetect the file format by looking at the first few bytes of the file, and comparing it against known file format signatures. That's because this tool can detect corruption only near the begininning of the file. I've already run such tools, and I already have a list a files with undetected formats.
- A tool which has gigabytes of dependencies, or it requires installing specific software for opening files (e.g. installing Microsoft Word just to determine whether a DOCX file is corrupt).
- A tool which does a physical I/O scan of the HDD/SSD/DVD. My storage medium works fine, there are no I/O errors.
- A tool which does a filesystem check and/or repair. The filesystem is fine, there are no errors.
- A tool which rereads files on a checksummed filesystem (e.g. ZFS or Btrfs) or checksummed RAID volume. I don't have such a filesystem.
- A tool which finds deleted files and undeletes them. None of the files I'm interested in are deleted.
- A tool which computes whole-file checksums (e.g. CRC-32, MD5, SHA-256) and compares files against known checksums. I don't have known-good checksums for these files.
- A tool which finds files with the wrong extension (i.e. extension not corresponding to the file format). I've already run such a tool, and all the files have the right extension.
- A tool which repairs corrupted files without asking first. I don't want to make changes to any of the files (yet). Maybe later I use some file repair software.
- A tool which isn't able to give me a list of corrupted files, which I can copy-paste to somewhere else. I need a full list which I can study, and make decisions about repairs later.

The tutorials I was able to find with a Google search are full of advice for something related, but which ultimately I don't need (see the list above).

Preferably, I'd like to get a tool recommended by a user who have used the tool successfully at least once for this purpose.

I was able to find the commercial software [Repairit](https://repairit.wondershare.com/tech-spec/). It supports dozens of file formats, but it's not obvious from the web page whether it can do what I need.

Comment: Have you consider to change the filesystem with some which support error correction (so you will have no corrupted files)?

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Yes, I've considered such protective measures for the future, but to the files mentioned in this question, the corruption has already happened already (see details in the question).

Comment: Write to support at RepairIt

Comment: @RohitGupta: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm still looking for software recommendations here. Surely there must be other software besides RepairIt, and Imd like to know about it.

Comment: If writing a program is an option, most of the work can be done using (LEADTOOLS SDKs)[https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/formats/product-comparison-chart]. (Disclosure: I work for the vendor). The RasterCodecs.Load() method supports hundreds of image, document and vector formats. Set the ThrowExceptionsOnInvalidImages Property to true, then loop through the millions of files you have. The method loads all pages from a file: it doesn't just examine the header, but converts the whole file to images and if it finds problems, raises an exception, which the program can catch and record in a log file.

Comment: @AminDodin: Sounds cool, you may want to add this as an answer. You may also want to give more details on what it checks for non-image file formats (e.g. does it verify the Adler32 checksum in ZIP archive members of .docx files?). (For hundreds of image file formats, there is already ImageMagick.)

Comment: @KJ: The claim *repair damaged PDF files without making any modifications to the original file* can be valid if the program creates a new PDF file, copying as much as possible from the corrupted input PDF file. Also in this question I'm not interested in repairing corruptions, just detecting them. For example, the program should find and decompress all PDF object streams, check compression checksums, and report any failures.

Comment: @pts I am ONLY considering PDF because I know that format best thus if streams are broke there is no easy means to say so the large number of examples I see are not externally easy to detect, nor "easy" to repair, as each will have different failings. One on a font another an image yet another some linework. the best you might do is as per other comments parse files through a %errorlevel%=1 process, technically many high percent of "working" PDF actually have several flaws.

Comment: @KJ: As I wrote in the question, I'm not interested in perfect validation of files. The tool should detect only the most blatant errors such as truncation or a random 4 KiB block being overwritten with garbage. So, for PDF it's enough to use the xref to find all objects, parse the object values, and decompress object streams. There is no need to verify that e.g. embedded font data is correct, and that the *q* and *Q* content stream operators match.

Comment: I didn't post as answer because the SDKs are not a ready solution. If you decide to build a solution, they can help you with much of the work but not all of it. For example, they support a wide range of image formats, document formats like PDF, DOCX and XLS, and vector drawing files like DWG and DXF, but they don't support things like ZIP or RAR archives. Also, there's no low-level access to the internals of every format. If a DOCX file is valid, it can be converted to other document formats or rendered as images, but you can't access individual contents of the encapsulating ZIP.

Comment: That's why there's a fully-functional free evaluation. Before you commit to investing time and money into building a solution using LEADTOOLS, you get a chance to try any functions or classes you might need, and you get to discuss with our support and sales teams issues like license cost, code performance and optimal ways to use the SDKs (all of this with no strings attached).

Comment: Many zip programs like 7zip have a built-in tester, but only for zip files as zip files contain CRC or similar for each file. 7z t <archive-name>  This is where you would use a dos or bash **for** loop to automate the process.

Comment: @cybernard: Indeed, `7z t` is a very useful command, because 7-Zip supports dozens of archive file formats for extraction. You may want to add it as an answer. (For image files, I can use ImageMagick in a `for` loop.)

Answer (score 2):

Many zip programs like 7zip have a built-in tester, but only for zip files as zip files contain CRC or similar for each file.  This is where you would use a dos or bash for loop to automate the process.

```
7z t <archive-name>
```

Linux

```
for i in `find / -iname "*.zip"`;do 7z t $i>>log.txt;done
```

More good news docx files are compressed .doc files so 7z t can check them also.

Comment: This is great! 7-Zip can extract dozens of archive file formats, thus with this command I can check many file formats.